# How to set the Cursor back to position zero after clearing a TextArea in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, textarea

I am using a textarea in my GWT application:

```
    @UiField
    TextArea inputArea;
```

When the user hits the return key the text should be deleted and the cursor should be set to the beginning of the textbox.

I tried the following:

```
 inputArea.setText("");
```

This is not working. The textbox seems to be empty, but the cursor is at the beginning of the second line of the textbox, not at the beginning of the first line of the textbox, where it should be.

I also tried it with:     inputArea.setCursorPos(0); but it did not worked.

How can I make sure that the cursor is set at the beginning of line one after the text is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
inputArea.setText( "" );
inputArea.setFocus( true );
inputArea.setCursorPos( 0 );
```

Comment: Whats the browser that you are using ? i have checked in chrome and FF. it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I created text area with highlighted prompt text.If you start typing directly - you do not need cursor. If you click on text area - prompt disappears and cursor is shown at zero position. Sure, it's not the most beautiful code, but it works in Eclipse.

```
inputArea.setText("Input your text here");
inputArea.selectAll();

inputArea.setOnMouseClicked(event-> {
   inputArea.setText(" ");
   inputArea.end();
   inputArea.deletePreviousChar();
} );
```